# Fabric and init

Tags: init, fabric

I am using fabric to restart tomcat and even though it says tomcat restarted successfully it does not. So, as per the FAQ, I set pty=False and tried again. But, now, I get this error:

`sudo: /etc/init.d/tomcat restart

out: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Any ideas around this problem?

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but did you do it like `sudo(...)` or like `run('sudo ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone reading this, this is not a problem with fabric but with the way sudo accounts have been set up. This property in /etc/sudoers file controls this;

Defaults    requiretty